# Error installing python library simple-crypt in Linux

Tags: python, linux, libraries, python-simple-crypt

I am getting error while installing python library simple-crypt in linux whereas I have installed it on windows 10. Python version on linux server is 2.7.
Can someone please let me know how can I resolve the issue.

I am getting error as below:-

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycrypto (from simple-crypt==4.1.7) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycrypto (from simple-crypt==4.1.7)

Comment: May be you can try install pycrypto manualy before install  simple-crypt

Answer (score 0):

I have Kali Linux and it works for me with the command:

```
pip install simple-crypt
```

If you don't have pip install it:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3-pip
```